# jQuery string formatting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, string, formatting

I'm trying to achieve the effect shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kyromedia/BnRfJ/

and get it to work on here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kyromedia/GJx3D/3/

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(".carousel_dp_home_price").each(function (index, elem) {
    var price = $(elem);
    var oldHtml = price.html();
    var newHtml = oldHtml.replace(/(\.\d+)$/,'<span class="carousel_dp_home_cents">$1</span>').replace('$', '');
price.html(newHtml);
});
```

Basically the script takes a string from a div with defined class, removes the "$" symbol and puts the decimal point and all characters after it in a span.

I'm not able to get the cents span to be generated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling the JQuery library, you should either remove the $ (end-of-string marker) from your regexp, or remove any newline after the prices themselves (in the original version they are not present):

```
/(\.\d+)/
```

Please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3FuR/.